# Random number with probability

Tags: php, math, random, numbers, probability

I am trying to generate a random number and have a probability of x% to get closer of the max value.

Problem is that I have no idea how to do this, unless I make some steps?

Let's say I'll generate a random number between 1 and 3000.

```
$number = mt_rand(1, 3000)
```

This will return 2700 for example. I would like it to be closer to 1 than 3000.

How should I implement a function that will only have a 10% chance to get near 3000?

Comment: Can you explain "near 3000"? is it "between 2500-3000" or "2900-3000"?

Comment: More likely to get the smallest amount possible (let`s say a range of 1-100) but still have that 10% chance to get near 3000 (with a range of 1000-3000).

Comment: The question is how you divide the ranges... what exactly is "near 3000" (you still didn't answer this)

Comment: Ok. So I should set the range to 1 - 100 most of the time. But still have a 10% chance to make the range 1 - 3000.

Comment: Define "near 3000"? Is this curve symmetrical, like a bell curve? It's hard to devise a specific solution to a vague problem statement. You should try to define your terms more clearly.

Comment: What about generating a random number between 0 and 1, and using `log()` or `sin()` or `cos()` tweaking the curve formulaically to get the proportions you want and symmetry or lack thereof, and use the resulting  value of the curve deflection along the appropriate axis as a percentage of your target range (in this case 3000)?  You could control the 'chances' of of hitting numbers at the extrema that way.

Comment: Or you could try to control the percentages by making smaller random numbers and using a switch statement with each case defining a different range, then choose a new random number within each range, or some less analog scheme like that.

Comment: Or you could pre-populate a larger array, let's say 300,000 elements, with numbers with each number repeated based on the % of time it should be hit, then choose a number between 0 and 300,000 and pluck the value out of that entry in the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question you can use the `mt_rand` function twice. First - to check if it should be the 90% (where the value is random of 1-100), and if not - it is the other 10%, where the value is random of 1-3000:

```
$number = mt_rand(0, 9) == 0 ? mt_rand(1, 3000) : mt_rand(1, 100);
```

Comment: Great idea. Thank you very much.